# adding update panel programmatically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am adding an update panel dynamically.
I am creating a dynamic table also and I have a button control in the table. when I click the button, I just want the table to be loaded again. So, I added this table to the update panel
UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(table);
I added the update panel to the page 
placeHolder1.Controls.Add(UpdatePanel1);

But when I click the button, the whole page is getting loaded.

How can I solve this?

Comment: My scriptmanager is in master page and update panel is being added dynamically in the child page

Answer (score 0):

I solved it finally...

I need to set EnablePartialRendering=true. in the master page of scriptmanager tag.

That solved my issue.